# How do I read from ISO-8859-1 stream while converting to UTF-8 in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I am trying to read from a ISO-8859-1 file and convert to UTF-8 before parsing it. I looked for some examples using Boost locale (example below), but couldn't make it work.

What is the recommended way for handling this case?

```
DefFile parse(std::istream &input);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::fstream file;

  boost::locale::generator gen;
  gen.categories(boost::locale::codepage_facet | boost::locale::convert_facet);
  file.imbue(gen.generate("pt_BR.ISO-8859-1"));
  file.open("RD2008.DEF", std::fstream::in);

  auto df = parse(file);
  // ... do some work
}
```

Comment: Maybe consider using `std::wifstream` instead. Imbued with a ISO-8859-1 locale, it should be able to read in ISO-8859-1 input and output converted `std::wstring` strings (UTF-16 on Windows, UTF-32 on other platforms), which you can then convert to UTF-8 as needed, such as with `std::wstring_convert`, or a 3rd party library like ICU, libiconv, etc. Or even manually (UTF<->UTF conversions are fairly easy to code by hand)